# What is the difference between XmlElement Class and XmlElementAttribute Class in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

From what I understand I use XmlElement Class to manipulate XML elements with Linq to XML and the XmlElementAttribute Class to mark a member of a given class as an xml element to be serialized.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `XmlElement` is not used with LINQ to XML. LINQ to XML uses `XElement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XmlElement is a part of "System.Xml" name space. This class is used for regular XML parsing.

XmlElement is not part of LINQ.

The XML classes related to "LINQ TO XML" are available in "System.Xml.Linq" name space. All LINQ related XML classes are listed in below link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq(v=vs.110).aspx

when it comes to "XmlElementAttribute", this is part of XML serialization. I mean when you are serializing the objects into XML, this class comes in to picture. (System.Xml.Serialization)

Comment: Can you please give an example on the "regular XML parsing"? That's what I fail to understand.

Comment: For example.... There is XML content in a file or a memory stream. You want to read it and do some changes and write it back to file or stream.

Comment: Ok, Pavan. Now I get it. Thank you.